# VBA - combining two worksheet change events

Tags: excel

Afternoon,

I have a worksheet change event the code is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K6:K50")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsDate(Target) Then
            MsgBox "You have entered a date in Attempt 5, you must now send an email to request a text message chaser, click ok to open the email to be sent", vbOKOnly, "Warning"
            Send_Emails
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Send_Emails()
'This code is early binding i.e in Tools > Reference >You have check "MICROSOFT OUTLOOK 14.0 OBJECT LIBRARY"

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutlookMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial>Hi, <br> <br> Can a new text chaser be sent to the client of this file please? <br> <br> <br> <br> Thank you </BODY>" & .HTMLBody
        'last .HTMLBody includes signature from the outlook.
                                                   '<br> includes line breaks b/w two lines
        .To = "xxx"
        .CC = "xxx"
        .Subject = "New Text Message chaser request"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

This event looks for a date in a given range and then produces a pop box and then when Ok is clicked an email message appears. This works fine.

I now have the below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Selection_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 24 Then
    Target.Offset(1, -19).Select
End If
End Sub
```

This code from what i understand is supposed to activate when enter is pressed in a cell in column X and then move to the next blank cell in Column E ready for data entry. Im told that you cant have more than one worksheet_change event in a worksheet, is there a way to have them both work with the same sheet but not tied to each other i.e i want them both to trigger independently of each other.

If this can not be done, can someone help me to figure out how to go from a Cell in Col X to the next blank cell of Col E ready for the next line of data entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere,

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Column > 24 Then Cells(Target.Row + 1, "E").Select
End Sub